# Disable background loading of user profile before logging in

Tags: windows-10, boot, login, multiple-users

I have a multi-user installation of Windows 10 (a private and a work profile). When starting the computer, the last logged-in user is preselected and when logging in, the profile is loaded immediately, whereas when switching to the other user, it takes some time.

It feels like Windows would be auto-loading the last used user profile in the background before even logging in.

This suspicion is being substantiated by the fact that when I login to the account that has **not** being used recently, there are still some applications *from the other user* running in background. When shutting down the computer, I would then get a warning "Other users are still logged in, do you really want to shutdown the computer?", even if I didn't login with another user.

My guess is that Windows loads the recently used profile in the background directly during the startup process.

**Is there a way to deactivate this behavior?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into the Fast Startup feature of Windows 10.

This feature allows your computer to start up faster after a shutdown.
When you shut down your computer, Fast Startup will put your computer
into a *hibernation state* instead of a full shutdown.
Fast Startup is enabled by default if your computer is capable of
hibernation.

See
[How to disable Windows 10 fast startup (and why you'd want to)](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup).

Comment: unfortunately switching off fast startup didn't change anything belonging the logon situation.

Comment: There can be no "leftovers" after a cold boot without Fast Startup. If you're seeing tasks running under another account, they can only be scheduled tasks or system services that are configured to run under that account.

Comment: the problem is not that there were leftovers after a cold boot, the problem is that after starting the computer the first selected user is being auto-logged in in the background and when switching to a different user, the first selected user's programs are still running. for now, I disabled fast user switching so there aren't any duplicate instances of programs such as Nextcloud running, however I'm still wondering why Windows makes that weird background loading even before logging in. need to find a solution on that.

Comment: It's possible that you're seeing [SuperFetch](https://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-windows-superfetch/), which is the preload into memory of often-used apps. This only preloads, but does not execute.

Comment: that sounds reasonable, thanks for that, I'll try if this works.